# Resize when double clicking ListView doesnt work properly

Tags: c#, forms, listview

I have my own ListView class, inheriting from Forms.ListView. When double clicking on the line between the columns, the columns resize to show the column items in full size.

HOWEVER, for me this doesnt work properly - some words are partially hidden.

My theory is that this is due to the items having different fonts and that the ListView doesnt look at them all, causing some larger font items to still be partially hidden.

Anyone got a solution to this problem (I cant seem find any event for when double clicking between columns)? And is my theory plausible?

best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could try with this code, I wrote it now, tested and it worked for me. Note that on my computer `ColumnwidthChanging` event is firing on each pixel changed (when you resize column using mouse) and on double click it changes for more than two pixels.Iam passing Font that is set for the list. You should do it with the font for particular ListViewItem. Try it out and if it works for you than that's it.

```
        private void listView1_ColumnWidthChanging(object sender, ColumnWidthChangingEventArgs e)
        {
            ListView lv = (ListView)sender;
            int widthDifference = Math.Abs(lv.Columns[ e.ColumnIndex].Width - e.NewWidth);
            if( widthDifference>2)
            {
                int maxWidth = 0;
                Graphics g = lv.CreateGraphics();
                for(int i = 0;i<lv.Items.Count;i++) 
                {
                    string text = string.Empty;
                    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
                    {
                        text = lv.Items[i].Text;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        text = lv.Items[i].SubItems[e.ColumnIndex - 1].Text;
                    }
                    SizeF sizeF = g.MeasureString(text, lv.Font);
                    if (maxWidth < (int)(sizeF.Width + 0.5))
                        maxWidth = (int)(sizeF.Width + 0.5);
                }
                g.Dispose();
                e.NewWidth = maxWidth;
            }
        }
```

EDIT:These are the settings for my `ListView` in Form1.Designer.cs, I think this can help you:

```
 this.listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
 this.listView1.GridLines = true;
 this.listView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(253, 160);
 this.listView1.Name = "listView1";
 this.listView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(428, 97);
 this.listView1.TabIndex = 9;
 this.listView1.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
 this.listView1.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
 this.listView1.ColumnWidthChanging += new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnWidthChangingEventHandler(this.listView1_ColumnWidthChanging);
```

Comment: @drbaltar Have you tried it? I'm curious if it is working in your particular case.

Comment: This looks very promising! However, the event never fires for some reason :S

Comment: I also tried enabling the "Show Window Contents While Dragging", as this seems to be needed for the event to fire, doesn't seem to be enough though.

Comment: @drbaltar I have posted the settings from the listView when I tried the code. It worked very good. Are you sure you are setting the event like shown in the EDIT of the question?

Comment: Thanks Nick! Works perfectly now!